# How to use bat to get values from .ini file where the value contains '='

Tags: batch-file, properties, io

Using codes like below:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (test.ini) do (
  if "%%i"=="mvn_command" set mvn_command=%%j
)
```

The value I get from such file:

test.ini (has below line as its content)

```
mvn_command=mvn install -DMAJOR_VERSION=1.0 -Dbuildenv=dev
```

is:

```
mvn_command=mvn install -DMAJOR_VERSION
```

which is not what is expected.

Even put the value in quotes did not work.

Is there any trick to play here as a solution?
Or any other way to read the expected value? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to indicate that you want the first token and, not the second token, but the rest of the line

```
tokens=1,*
```

that is the first token goes to the first replaceable parameter (`%%i` in your code) and the rest of the line to the second one (`%%j` in your code)

Comment: Thanks MC for so prompt a solution. It works great. I used many bat scripts, but did not quite understand the semantics. Appreciated.